# How to show alert box from php and passed to ajax response?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to show a message to show that my insert sql was successfully inserted. 
Here's my code below.

insert.php

```
    $added = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    if($added){
      echo "show";   
    }
}
```

After the php i will be passing the response to ajax that looks like the code below. I want to show the message with toastr.

ajax.js

```
<script>         
    $.post("addTournament.php", {
        TournamentName: TournamentName,
        RegistrationStartDate: RegistrationStartDate,
        RegistrationEndDate: RegistrationEndDate,
        TournamentStartDate: TournamentStartDate,
        TournamentEndDate: TournamentEndDate,
        SystemOfPlay: SystemOfPlay,
            Venue: Venue
        }, function (data, status) {

            $("#add_modal").modal("hide");
            ViewTournament();
            if (data == "show") {
                toastr.success('Tournament Added!', 'Success Alert', {timeOut: 5000})
            }
        })
</script>
```

Comment: Please show us what error are you receiving or what is the actual result you are seeing.

Comment: That code looks ok, what seems to be the problem?

Comment: There was no error and the toastr won't show up

Comment: Have you tried printing to console before toastr and see if it even reaches toastr?

Comment: console wont reach the toastr, i tried it now.

Comment: in that case you _must_ have an error of some kind. Check your network tab as well for the status of the request to addTournament.php